# how to add textfield delegate in swift

Tags: swift, uitextfielddelegate

I need to add delegate to textfields; my understanding is it can be done two ways:

1. we go to file and viewController.swift and under class, after UIviewcontroller we add comma and then type UITextFieldDelegate .
   and then u under viewDidLoad we add method and function
2. when on storyboard we click and drag textfield to small icon on top of view that says view controller and pick delegate

Do they both work the same? or there is difference if we do one way or the other?
and what you do if you have more than one textfields, I have 10 textfields and have 7 functions and buttons, I need to do this so I can disable button if my textfield is empty for that button.

Answer (score 1):

There is no difference, as far as I know. Choose what you like more.

In first case you also need to make `@IBOutlet` for your `UITextField`(click and drag `UITextField` from `UIStoryboard` to your `UIViewController` code) and after that make `UIViewController` delegate of `UITextField`

For example:

```
import UIKit

class MyViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate
{
    @IBOutlet weak var myTextField: UITextField!

    override func viewDidLoad()
    {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        myTextField.delegate = self
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you so much for your time and help, so I have to create  IBoutlet for all my textfields, right? and when add myTextField.delegate = self, you do this to all textfields?     thank you so much for all your help

Comment: Yes, you need to create `@IBOutlet` for each `UITextField` and add delegate for each `UITextField` also

Comment: How you do that ? I m very new here , don't know much about how this works